# EOF going into infinite loop

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

I am greping and awking some text from a file and writing it to another one.

When I am trying to open and read log_2 to do something, it works fine in case the grep returned some string.

But if grep itself *dint return anything* , my code is going into an infinite loop. I tried printing the character being read in the loop, it prints a ' ÿ ' infinitely.

```
system("egrep 'Security = |State = ' log.txt > log_1.txt");
system("awk -F ' Security = | State = { Interface=' '{print $2}' log_1.txt > log_2.txt ");

// The exact strings to be greped and awked are different. Cant write them here.    

FILE *pReadFile;
char cTemp;

pReadFile=fopen ( "log_2.txt" , "r+");

if (pReadFile==NULL )
{
    std::cout << ("Error opening Config file");
    fclose(pReadFile);
    return ;
}

cTemp = fgetc (pReadFile);

if(cTemp == EOF)    
return ; 


while( cTemp != EOF )
{
      // Do Something

      cTemp = fgetc (pReadFile);
}
```

Can someone explain ?

---

Just to add in case someone is having similar issue, this code works fine on Intel based Ubuntu systems, but Freescale ones with Ubuntu will cause a problem. So be careful, and always use int to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EOF` is an `int` not a `char`.

```
char cTemp;
```

should be:

```
int Temp;
```

See here for the explanation:

http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: I am using this code to parse a file and do some matching with a regular expression. I have done matching with different characters assuming cTemp to be char type only. Will it work just fine if I just change the datatype to int, int and char being castable to each other ?